# Finding a symmetric adjacency matrix closest to a given (non-symmetric) adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, discrete-optimization, binary-programming, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to solve a problem on graphs, which I have reduced to the following optimization problem in matrix $X \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| X - A \|_F^2\\ \text{subject to} & X 1_n = m 1_n\\ & X=X^\top\end{array}$$

where matrix $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ is given. Matrix $X$ is the adjacency matrix of a non-directed $m$-regular graph, while matrix $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a directed graph.

I am quite clueless on how to go on solving this problem and would be happy to get a direction.

Comment: Are all those conditions saying that $X$ is adjacency matrix or am I missing some subtlety there?

Comment: X is an adjacency matrix for a non directed graph, where each vertex is of rank m. While the input A is an adjacency matrix of a directed graph.

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer!

Comment: I'm guessing $||.||_F$ is Frobenius norm. And the min has to be taken along the undirected graph otherwise the obvious solution would be $X=A$.

Comment: The norm is Frobenius. As for the second observation,  $X=A$ would also not hold the constraint of the row sums, as we have no information about them in A.

Comment: Having thought about this, this is a case of integer quadratic programming (albeit that is an enormous class of problems) for sure but this doesn't have any efficient solutions (some algorithms for finding correct ones exist). I feel like there is a lot bigger chance at finding a non-terrible algorithm looking at the original graph problem. On the other hand if you're quite sure that no efficient algorithm exist maybe there is a chance to show that there is a large class of QP problems that are equivalent.

Comment: If $A=\|a_{ij}\|$ then is it necessary that at most one of $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ij}$ equals $1$ for each $i,j$?

Answer (score 4):

We have the following optimization problem in matrix $\mathrm X \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm  X - \mathrm A \|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm  X 1_n = m 1_n\\ & \mathrm  X = \mathrm  X^\top\\ & \mathrm X \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}\end{array}$$

where matrix $\mathrm A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ is given. Note that

$$\| \mathrm  X - \mathrm A \|_{\text{F}}^2 = \| \mathrm  X \|_{\text{F}}^2 - 2 \langle \mathrm  A, \mathrm  X \rangle + \| \mathrm A \|_{\text{F}}^2$$

and that $\| \mathrm  X \|_{\text{F}}^2 = m n$, due to the constraints. Hence, we have the following **integer program** (IP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \langle \mathrm  A, \mathrm  X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm  X 1_n = m 1_n\\ & \mathrm  X = \mathrm  X^\top\\ & \mathrm X \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}\end{array}$$

which appears to be a generalization of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). Perhaps there is a generalization of the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), too.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/336396/91764